# How to display the coming birthdays using mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

i would like to display the future coming birthdays on my website , So order them using the date of birth(dateofb)
the below query is not displaying  the bateof births in dateofb order. It is displaying in order using id.

" the dateofb contains the set of date of births in this format 02 sept 1970 . "

```
<?php $sel = $db->query("select * from mov_biography order by dateofb asc limit 0,5"); 
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sel)){

echo ($row['name']); } ?>
```

Comment: that's because you are storing the dates wrong, you should be storing them in an appropriate date type

Comment: suggest the appropriate date type

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-types.html

Comment: is it possible to convert all the date format to correct one?

Answer (score 0):

You can do sumthing like that...

```
SELECT

  , MONTH(dateofb)  AS month
  , DAY(dateofb ) AS day  

FROM <table_name>
WHERE  birthday BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW, INTERVAL 90 DAY)  
ORDER BY Birthday DESC
```

Comment: will not work while date is stored as text, and if it was this is overkill

Answer (score 0):

With the default sort, it would look something like below:

```
mysql> SELECT column FROM table_name ORDER BY column; 

column
======
100
1000
10000
200
2000
20000
...

Now with "... ORDER BY column+0", I get it sorted right:

mysql> SELECT column FROM table_name ORDER BY column+0; 

column
======
100
200
1000
2000
10000
20000
...

This is a quick fix instead of sorting to CAST operator.
```

Comment: if not the you have to Use CAST Operator for text to SORT...USE Mysql Manual for that. hope it helps!